# Endpoint requests returns 404 not found for uber-api sandbox environment

Tags: python, uber-api

Uber apis `requests` endpoint in sandbox gives response as:

`u'<html><title>404: Not Found</title><body>404: Not Found</body></html>'` .

For sandbox I am using endpoint:

```
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests
```

Same request works fine if  I use uber prod endpoint

`https://api.uber.com/v1/requests`

I used python requests lib for api:

```
import request

params = {'start_longitude': 'xx.xxxxxx', 'end_longitude': 'xx.xxxxxx', 
          'start_latitude': 'xx.xxxxxx', 'end_latitude': 'xx.xxxxxx', 
          'product_id': '0dfc35e0-b4be-49a1-b1bf-0bc7217e4b58'}
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
          'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx-acces-token-xxx'`}

res = requests.post('https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests',
                     data=json.dumps(params), headers=headers)
```

And like I said this work if I change url to uber prod environment:

```
 res = requests.post('https://api.uber.com/v1/requests',
                      data=json.dumps(params), headers=headers)
```

Comment: What is the exact command you send? Which tool and which programming language?

Comment: Hey @martin I added details.

Comment: Sandbox url is https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests

Comment: if that is the answer, add it as an answer and accept it such that other  people can find it quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sandbox url for uber api is:-
 `https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests`